# This HTML code won't render

Tags: html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>QuickLinks</title>
    <style>
        body{
        overflow: all;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;    
        }
        a{
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="popup.html">Back to main</a>
            <hr id="85">
        
            <hr id="85">
        <div id="83">
          <a href="https://github.com/jHoyne/QuickLinks/issues" target="_blank">Issues</a>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will Not render in chrome. Not sure about others. File is saved as google.html and it is for a directory style chrome extension and will not render anywhere within chrome.

Comment: overflow has not property `all` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7xvLjyoc/

Comment: You're missing a closing `</style>` tag which might give you problems.

Comment: Usually all works I figured out aswell I forgot </style>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded some errors in your code.
 1.In your code there is no end style tag.
 2.  tag end with after end style tag.

I modifed your code. It's wroking fine.

```css
  <style>
body{
        overflow: all;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;    
        }
        a{
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
  </style>
```

```html
<head> </head>
<title>QuickLinks</title> 

     <body>
        <a href="popup.html">Back to main</a>
            <hr id="85">
        
            <hr id="85">
        <div id="83">
          <a href="https://github.com/jHoyne/QuickLinks/issues" target="_blank">Issues</a>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

use this more.

There are 7 errors I think according to the validator.

I noticed that your missing the <./style> tag. (ignore the '.').